# Solve the following differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Please solve this with methods which a calc AB student can understand. $dx/dt-10x=(e^t)^4$. Find $x(t)$. If it's not clear, the RHS is e to the power of 4t. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, when you have an equation like

$$x' + a x = b$$

the idea is to multiply both sides by $e^{a  t}$ so that the equation may be expressed as

$$\frac{d}{dt} (e^{a t} x) = b e^{a t}$$

$b$ may be a function of $t$ as well.  Anyway, I hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear first order ODE of the form $dx/dt + P(t)x = Q(t)$, so the general approach would be to calculate an integrating factor $$\mu = e^{\int P(t) dt}$$ and solve the following for $x$ $$\mu x = \int \mu Q(t) dt$$